# How to make bash script fail at the end when an error occurs in a pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

For now I'm using this in my script:

```
set -euxo pipefail
```

This will make my bash script fail immediatly if there is an error in my pipe.
When I leave this option my script will run fully and end with exit 0 (no error).

I want to have a mix of both. I want to end the whole script but have `exit 1`; at the end if there was an error in a pipe.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail
curl --fail --compressed -u "$CREDS" -X GET --header 'Accept: xxx' --header 'Accept-Language: de-DE' 'https://api/call1' | jq -S "." > "output1.json"
curl --fail --compressed -u "$CREDS" -X GET --header 'Accept: xxx' --header 'Accept-Language: de-DE' 'https://api/call2' | jq -S "." > "output2.json"
cat output1.json
cat output2.json
```

So I don't want to exit the script if `call1` fails. If `call1` fails I want to go to `call2` and the `cat` commands before exiting the script with `exit code 1`.

Comment: Closely related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450561/capture-non-zero-exit-code-from-named-pipe) on pipeline errors and how to deal with them. Please see that post for relevant answers also.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `set -e` as that will make script exit upon first error. Just save your exit codes after `call1` and `call2` and exit with appropriate exit code after `cat` commands:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash -ux
set -uxo pipefail

curl --fail --compressed -u "$CREDS" -X GET --header 'Accept: xxx' --header 'Accept-Language: de-DE' 'https://api/call1' | jq -S "." > "output1.json"
ret1=$?
curl --fail --compressed -u "$CREDS" -X GET --header 'Accept: xxx' --header 'Accept-Language: de-DE' 'https://api/call2' | jq -S "." > "output2.json"
ret2=$?

cat output1.json
cat output2.json

exit $((ret1 | ret2))
```

Comment: Without `set -o pipefail` if the first curl fails, the `$?` will be `0` anyway, because `jq` will/can succeed.

Comment: With `curl --fail` in place `jq` will fail if `curl` fails but we can surely add `set -o pipefail`

Answer (score 0):

Subshells.

```
set -euo pipefail
export SHELLOPTS

(
   set -euo pipefail
   curl --fail --compressed -u "$CREDS" -X GET --header 'Accept: xxx' --header 'Accept-Language: de-DE' 'https://api/call1' | jq -S "." > "output1.json"
) && res1=$? || res1=$?

(
   set -euo pipefail
   curl --fail --compressed -u "$CREDS" -X GET --header 'Accept: xxx' --header 'Accept-Language: de-DE' 'https://api/call2' | jq -S "." > "output2.json"
) && res2=$? || res2=$?

if (( res1 != 0 || res2 != 0 )); then
   echo "Och! Command 1 failed or command 2 failed, what is the meaning of life?"
   exit 1;
fi
```

Subshell let's you grab the return value of the commands executed in it.